# Manifest is not Valid JSON. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My manifest is shown down below. I'm not sure why Google Chrome always says that it is not a valid JSON and Dictionary Keys are not quoted. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
{
    "name": "Auto Add to Cart",
    "version": "1.2",
    "manifest_version": 2,
}
```

Comment: Nice pretty pictures:  http://json.org

Comment: You should check out [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com), it's a great tool for validating JSON.

Comment: This looks like someone created their JSON as a string in a loop.

Comment: @Paul As it's a manifest for a Chrome extension, it's probably just bad copy-pasta.

Comment: Still get the same message from Google Chrome. Even after fixing what was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a trailing comma in JSON. Remove the comma after the `2`.

Here's how an object is defined :

[image]

(source : [json.org](http://json.org/))

Comment: Still get the same message from Google Chrome. Even after fixing what was wrong.

Comment: The same message saying it's not JSON ? That's strange. Here's for example a manifest I made : https://github.com/Canop/braldop/blob/master/chrome/braldop/manifest.json